# PostgreSQL UNIQUE constraint violated without any error

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-14

I have the following table:

```
\d+ my_table;

                                                      Table "public.my_table"
 Column |       Type        | Collation | Nullable |           Default            | Storage  | Compression | Stats target | Description 
--------+-------------------+-----------+----------+------------------------------+----------+-------------+--------------+-------------
 pkey   | integer           |           | not null | generated always as identity | plain    |             |              | 
 name   | character varying |           |          |                              | extended |             |              | 

Indexes:
    "my_table_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (pkey)
    "my_table_name_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (name)
Access method: heap
```

How is it possible then, that I can get:

```
select name, count(*) from my_table group by name having count(*) > 1;

   name     | count 
------------+-------
 some_value |     2
(1 row)
```

The value is not null.

Tried inserting a duplicate manually:

```
INSERT INTO my_table("name") VALUES('some_value');
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "my_table_name_key"
DETAIL:  Key (name)=(some_value) already exists.

INSERT INTO my_table("name") VALUES('some_value') ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
INSERT 0 0
```

which works as expected.

I'm also tracking all statements that PostgreSQL gets (I set `log_statement = 'all'), but I can't see anything useful in there either.

Comment: So my question is more: what could circumvent the unique constraint and not show in logged statements?

Comment: That value is a *`null`* or your index is corrupted: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/nkvlMtTB). You can specify `unique nulls not distinct` to avoid the *`null`* case.

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63588123/6464308).

Comment: @Zegarek the value is not null.

Comment: @AdrianAzoitei Add clarifying info into the question, not comments. If it's not *`null`*, you're left with the corrupted index scenario.

Comment: If `REINDEX INDEX my_table_name_key;` fixes the problem then it was a corrupted index, most likely caused by a breaking change in an underlying OS library.